# wsgi import classes from folder

Tags: python, wsgi

I have the script:
**/home/ubuntu/.wsgi/main.wsgi**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('.')
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'See you at terokarvinen.com!\n'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

I would like to import a class from the directory:
**/home/ubuntu/.wsgi/modules/myclass.wsgi**

I am new to mod_wsgi.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Add a second path and import statement after line 2.